# Does an AWS Lightsail on Windows server only allow one TCP port?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does an AWS Lightsail on Windows server only allow one TCP port?

In this case, I can only use this

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/adminportal
```

But not tis

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1234
```

I have multiple websites to be hosted, can I host them with only one Lightsail Windows server?

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can definately host multiple websites on a lightsail server.  From a backend POV, you have full access to the VM and can do non-web stuff with it. (I turned one into a reverse proxy using iptables and a vpn - no web server in site, and not limited to web ports)

I'm not convinced there is much special compared to EC2
save maybe the setup is a little simplified and limited in instance choices.  For web hosting you would typically use standard SNI - standard  name based hosting). I know this works as I took over and dusmantled a lightsail server doing just that intil I fecomissioned it same way I might any other Linux based VM)

For multiple ports, like with EC2 & you need to open them under networking - ie outside the OS itself - in the Lightsail setup for the instance -https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-editing-firewall-rules - that said, this is not typically a good solution for mulriple hosts.

Comment: Maybe your issue is selecting HTTP in the cystom rule.  There is nothing special about HTTP other then its association with port 80.  Just open a regular TCP port - it looks like thats been done already in the rule below.